# Magento 2.4 does not contain index.php in root

Tags: magento2, installation

I am trying to install magento 2.4 on my local machine. When i try to access through url it shows directory structure https://prnt.sc/1jbghbf . I found that index.php is missing in the root directory. What can be done for this?
Please help me with the installation.

Answer (score 1):

What has happened is, they have implemented the "route everything through pub folder for security" approach.

You can find the file there.

Now Magneto Change the Structure, and website root folder is now "Pub" directory.

Comment: SO what i have to do to make it work?

Comment: You need to modify some configuration. Kindly check this one : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Comment: If my answer help you into the current question, please upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other into community as well.

Comment: I am getting this error during command line installtion   Class Magento\Config\Model\Config\StructureFactory does not exist

Comment: If you have different question ask separately, so other community member can also help you into that one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours, my method was simply to copy the index.php file from the pub folder to the outside, then edit the following line in the index.php file.

```
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just point your document root to /pub folder. You will find index.php there